# Why my server didn't restart after reboot command?

Tags: server, shutdown, reboot

I'm currently away (700Km) from my server, but did an apt upgrade through ssh and requested a reboot. The server stopped with a graceful shutdown but didn't restart.

A friend looked at the server and it was simply stopped as if I did a shutdown. Pressing the power button started the server and it now runs without a problem.

Log file inspection shows nothing abnormal. No errors, or anything. I see the log entries of the graceful shutdown.

What could cause this behavior ? What should I look at to investigate the possible cause ? I usually don't have a problem when rebooting this sever through ssh.

Since I'm still away from home until the end of the week I can retest it.

Answer (score 0):

`$ man shutdown`

```
  -r, --reboot
       Reboot the machine.
```

You forgot to include that option?

Check
`$ history | grep shutdown`
?

Comment: I used the command `sudo reboot`. I couldn't have made an error